# Trying to get all g-link from a google response

Tags: java, google-api, jsoup

I used the following code to generate the response from google to a specific search:

```
String userInput="Lemon Bars";
String google = "http://www.google.com/search?q=";
Connection.Response response =Jsoup.connect(google+userInput)
    .ignoreContentType(true)
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
    .timeout(12000)
    .followRedirects(true)
    .execute();
```

I`m trying to get access to all the g-links type elements to be able to collect all of them and calculate some logic based on the values of these DOMs. ( 
I am unable to get those elements and I don't know what is the problem.
Once I can get those elements I would like to collect more the just the first 3 cards (that are the default visible cards) as if I pressed the "show more" button around 3 times so I can collect at least 30 g-link elements.
[image: deafult 3 links and getting more]

this is the select I tried:
`Elements links = doc.select("g-link");`
which returns 0 elements

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, when making the search in google the way I did here, I don't get the same page as searching in the browser.

I guess part of the page is built via scripting (Lazy loading) or in the browser.

The simple reason I can`t get the g-link elements from my HTML source is that it is not present in the source I got back using the Following method